# Create TestClass for Interface with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xunit, autofixture

Hello I have code like below and use xUnit. I would like to write TestClass to test my interface. Could you tell my how can I:

- inject different services to test class by DependencyInjection and run test for this services.
- prepare object to inject with Autofixture and AutoMoq. Before inject i would like to create services like

I want to do somethink like this :

```
public ServiceTestClass
{
    private ISampleService sut;
    public ServiceTestClass(ISampleService service) {
        this.sut = service;
    }

    [Fact]
    public MyTestMetod() {
        // arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();

        // act
        sut.MakeOrder();  

        // assert
        Assert(somethink);
    }
}


public class SampleService : ISampleService // ande few services which implements ISampleService
{
    // ISampleUow also include few IRepository
    private readonly ISampleUow uow;
    public SampleService(ISampleUow uow) {
        this.uow = uow;
    }

    public void  MakeOrder() {
        //implementation which use uow
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't particularly clear what you're asking, but AutoFixture can serve as an [Auto-mocking Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container). The [AutoMoq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq) Glue Library is one of many extensions that enable AutoFixture to do that. Others are [AutoNSubstitute](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute), [AutoFakeItEasy](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoFakeItEasy), etc.

This enables you to write tests like this one:

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<ISampleUow>>();
    var sut = fixture.Create<SampleService>();

    sut.MakeOrder();

    mock.Verify(uow => /* assertion expression goes here */);
}
```

If you combine it with the AutoFixture.Xunit2 Glue Library, you can condense it to this:

```
[Theory, MyAutoData]
public void MyTest([Frozen]Mock<ISampleUow> mock, SampleService sut)
{
    var sut = fixture.Create<SampleService>();    
    sut.MakeOrder();    
    mock.Verify(uow => /* assertion expression goes here */);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answer but you didn't understand me. First I want to call my ServiceTestClass constructor with ISampleServiceArgument and run tests.
Second u would like to use fixture.Create with ISampleService - not SampleService.

Comment: @user2811005 As given in the OP, `ServiceTestClass` doesn't have a constructor that takes `ISampleService` as an argument. Even if it had, AFAICT, it's a test class, which means that it's whatever *test runner* you use that creates instances of that class. Unless you go out of your way, *xUnit.net* expects that class to have a parameterless constructor (which it currently has).

Comment: I have done mistake in my sample code -fogotten about constructor. I have just fixed it.  But it doesn't matter.  So, to sum up - as you said It doesn;t possible to create constructor with parametr in TestClass ?

Comment: @user2811005 It's a question if *xUnit.net* contains the extensibility points for that. IIRC, *xUnit.net 1* had a hook that could enable you to do something like that, but it was a lot of trouble, so not practical. I haven't looked into *xUnit.net 2* enough to know whether or not that's possible.

Comment: @user2811005 In any case, *why* do you want to do this? That's not a normal thing to do, so I wonder if there's a usage scenario I haven't seen before...